# How to split /etc/network/interfaces using a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to break the `/etc/network/interfaces` file format on Ubuntu to the individual stanzas (as the man page calls them).

This is the sample interfaces file I test my script against:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.0.2.254
    dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.43
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8::c0ca:1eaf
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:db8::1ead:ed:beef

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.10.0.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    up /usr/sbin/brctl stp br0 on
```

What I need is an array of strings holding each stanza (`iface`, `mapping`, `auto`, `allow-\w+`, `source(-\w+)?` and comments) along with all the text that follows it until the start of next stanza.

I've tried code like this, which sounds like it should work, but it captures all stanzas in one string:

```
re.split(r'^(iface|mapping|auto|allow-\w+|source(-\w)?|#.*)[.\n]+?',
    open('/etc/network/interfaces').read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

How can I correct the regex to achieve this?

Python version is 2.7

Comment: to clarify, each stanza would be one of the block of information separated by blank lines?

Comment: @timgeb No each stanza is from the start of one of the keywords to the start of next one, including all the lines between them (for example options for `static` method in an `iface` stanza like `address` and `netmask` should all be part of `iface` stanza and therefore in the same string).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the definition of stanza. You should probably update your post with the information what your expected result for the sample file is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
def stanza(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        vals = ("iface", "mapping", "auto", "allow-", "source")
        tmp = []
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(vals):
                yield tmp
                tmp = [line]
            else:
                tmp.append(line)
    if tmp:
        yield tmp


from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(list(stanza("foo.txt")))
```

Output:

```
[['# The loopback network interface\n'],
 ['auto lo\n'],
 ['iface lo inet loopback\n', '\n'],
 ['auto eth0\n'],
 ['iface eth0 inet static\n',
  '    address 192.168.2.7\n',
  '    netmask 255.255.255.0\n',
  '    network 192.168.2.0\n',
  '    broadcast 192.168.2.255\n',
  '    gateway 192.0.2.254\n',
  '    dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79\n',
  '\n'],
 ['auto eth0:0\n'],
 ['allow-hotplug eth0:0\n'],
 ['iface eth0:0 inet static\n',
  '    address 192.168.1.43\n',
  '    netmask 255.255.255.0\n',
  '\n'],
 ['auto eth1\n'],
 ['iface eth1 inet dhcp\n', '\n'],
 ['auto eth2\n'],
 ['iface eth2 inet6 static\n',
  '    address 2001:db8::c0ca:1eaf\n',
  '    netmask 64\n',
  '    gateway 2001:db8::1ead:ed:beef\n',
  '\n'],
 ['auto br0\n'],
 ['iface br0 inet static\n',
  '    address 10.10.0.15\n',
  '    netmask 255.255.255.0\n',
  '    gateway 10.10.0.1\n',
  '    bridge_ports eth0 eth1\n',
  '    up /usr/sbin/brctl stp br0 on']]
```

If you want to remove the whitespace strip it off with `line.strip()`.